# unix AIX - get the status of a child background process in the parent shell script

Tags: unix, sh

I have a parent shell which calls a child shell as background process. 
In the child shell i send a exit to parent , it is required to capture the status of child in parent process. I am using "jobs" command for the same. I am able to capture the running status of the child , but I dont get the Done status in the parent.
PLease find below the code and the output -

Parent Shell:

```
#!/bin/ksh
date
./sleep.com&
echo $?
echo $!
pid=$!
echo $pid
jobs $pid
wait $pid
jobs $pid
echo $pid
```

Child shell (sleep.com- background process):

```
#!/bin/ksh
sleep 8
exit 10
```

Output of execution-

```
September 11, 2017 at 07:58:17 PM 
0
12517444
12517444
[1] +  Running                 <command unknown>
./parent.com[10]: jobs: no such job
12517444
```

Please help me capture the status of `jobs` command post completion of child.

In my case I get an error:

> ./parent.com[10]: jobs: no such job

Thanks & Regards

Himanshu Agrawal.

Answer (score 0):

Try `wait -n`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -v
date
./sleep.com&
echo $?
pid=$!
echo $pid
wait -n $pid
child_exit=$?
printf 'child exited with code %d\n' "$child_exit"
```

Comment: thanks Lorinczy. It gives me the output of child process in the variable. but I have a need to remove the wait command, which means the child process is in background , still i should be able to get the status of child. I had googled that I can use jobs command to do the same, but when i use in the shell it gives me "no such process" after the completion of process. please suggest.

Comment: You could use an actual programming language that has signal-support: you will get a SIGCHILD signal when the child exits.